# File not saved in Android

Tags: android, file, save

I'm trying to create a simple Android app which saves a text from an EditText form and store it in internal memory. Everything seems to work fine (the "Saved" message appears) except when I quit the activity and restart it, the saved text from file does not load at all. Am I missing something here?

```
public class ModifyInfo extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(extras != null){
        int dayNum = extras.getInt("day");
        String dayName = "";

        switch(dayNum){
        case 1:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.dayMon);
            break;
        case 2:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.dayTue);
            break;
        case 3:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.dayWed);
            break;
        case 4:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.dayThu);
            break;
        case 5:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.dayFri);
            break;
        case 6:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.daySat);
            break;
        default:
            dayName = this.getString(R.string.daySun);
            break;
        }

        final TextView dayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dayName);
        final TextView editData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editData);
        final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        final Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
        final String Day = dayName;

        dayText.setText(dayName);

        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editData.setText("");
            }
        });

        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String FILEOUTPUT = Day + ".txt";

                try {
                    String string = editData.getText().toString();

                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILEOUTPUT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(string.getBytes());
                    fos.close();

                    Toast.makeText(ModifyInfo.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ModifyInfo.this, "Save error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
            }
        });

        File FILEINPUT = new File(Day + ".txt");

        try {
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEINPUT));
            String line;

            while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null)
            {
                editData.setText(line);
            }

            bfr.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            editData.setText("");
        }   
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: I would improve exception handling. In general it is not a good habit to catch an instance of Exception class. You should better log exceptions so that u know when they are thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that android locks files from some folders and you can not modify them. You can use sharedpreferences or static objects.

Comment: Do I have to set some permission?

Comment: I could not set it . Check it from os see the properties of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be reading \n or such whitespace from the last line of the file, since you are calling  editData.setText(line); , which resets the text to current line .
Or you may also be experiencing an Exception, in that case you are handling that Exception by clearing editText.

It should be like this instead:

```
try {
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILEINPUT));
        String line;
        String fullText = "";

        while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null)
        {
            fullText += line;
        }

        bfr.close();

        editData.setText(fullText);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        editData.setText("");
    }
```

According to your clarification, you should check that you open your file correctly as stated in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

To read a file from internal storage:

```
1. Call openFileInput() and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
2. Read bytes from the file with read().
3. Then close the stream with close().
```

You are trying to open using BufferedReader instead.

Comment: It keeps returning a file not found exception, which means the file isn't properly stored, if at all. Is there anything wrong with my save.setOnClickListener?

Comment: I revised my answer. Could you please check with openFileInput() ?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but I managed to fix it using SharedPreferences, which turns out to be much simpler. Sorry for the trouble.